# Multilevel menus don't hover left or right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, submenu, multi-level

I've added multilevel menu's on my site, but I can't seem to get them to hover to the left or the right. When you click over the menu "ZIEN" and hover over the first "BRILLEN" the submenus  appear underneath instead of left or right (wich is my wish). Anybody got any tips?

I hope my explanation is clear.

Thanks a bunch!

Sorry forgot the link: http://turnhoutoptiek.nl/index2.html

Thanks for the awnser! I've been looking a bit further and came up with the next thing: I deleted "dropdown-submenu" from the classes that had this class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu" and changed this in the css:

```
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu
{
width:220px;
top:0;
    left:100%;
    margin-top:-6px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
}
```

to:

```
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu
{
width:220px;
top:0;
    left:100% !important;
    margin-top:-6px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the submenu position to relative and then set a left value as wide as needed

```
<style>
    .dropdown-submenu{position: relative; left:100px;}
</style>
```